# Synonym for /synchronization and /sync?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Two tags exist for questions dealing with "synchronizing":

- [synchronization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) (9)
- [sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) (17)

From the current questions asked, there are three uses for them:

- File synchronization between machines (`rsync` and others)
- Time synchronization (`ntp` and related)
- Device synchronization (for PDAs or other devices)

Should the two existing tags be made synonyms, or should more specific tags be created instead - [file-sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sync), [time-sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-sync), [device-sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-sync) maybe?

If synonymized, not sure which one should be the parent. [synchronization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) seems more "proper", but [sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) is short and sweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Device synchronization is file synchronization under the hood, and sometimes uses the same tools and sometimes not.

I don't think it hurts to have a slightly ambiguous [synchronization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) tag. You're still synchronizing information in any case.

[sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) should be a synonym of [synchronization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization). Lazy typists can still type the four-letter form, and the display name will be clearer. Also, [sync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sync) close enough to [rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rsync) that it's confused occasionally.

Comment: Added the synonym and merged